# Script gets stuck while sending post requests with parameters

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to populate json response issuing a post http requests with appropriate parameters from a webpage. When I run the script, I see that the script gets stuck and doesn't bring any result. It doesn't throw any error either. This is the [site link](https://www.thetrainline.com/). I chose three options from the three dropdowns from [this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQrdd.jpg) in that site before hitting `Get times & tickets` button.

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.thetrainline.com/'
link = 'https://www.thetrainline.com/api/journey-search/'

payload = {"passengers":[{"dateOfBirth":"1991-01-31"}],"isEurope":False,"cards":[],"transitDefinitions":[{"direction":"outward","origin":"1f06fc66ccd7ea92ae4b0a550e4ddfd1","destination":"7c25e933fd14386745a7f49423969308","journeyDate":{"type":"departAfter","time":"2021-02-11T22:45:00"}}],"type":"single","maximumJourneys":4,"includeRealtime":True,"applyFareDiscounts":True}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    s.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json'
    s.headers['accept'] = 'application/json'
    r = s.post(link,json=payload)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.json())
```

> How can I get json response issuing post requests with parameters from that site?

Comment: You can view the full requests debug logs by setting the root log level to debug. It's hard for us to help answer a question like this without seeing the traffic. An alternative would be to watch your traffic using something like Fiddler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the required headers: `x-version` and `referer`. The `referer` header is referring to the search form and you can build it. Before `journey-search` you have to post an `availability` request.

```
import requests
from requests.models import PreparedRequest

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.thetrainline.com',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'x-version': '2.0.18186',
    'dnt': '1',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'origin': 'https://www.thetrainline.com',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    origin = "6e2242b3f38bbbd8d8124e1d84d319e1"
    destination = "15bcf02bc44ea754837c8cf14569f608"
    localDateTime = "2021-02-03T19:30:00"
    dateOfBirth = "1991-02-03"
    passenger_type = "single"

    req = PreparedRequest()
    url = "http://www.neo4j.com"
    params = {
        "origin": origin,
        "destination": destination,
        "outwardDate": localDateTime,
        "outwardDateType": "departAfter",
        "journeySearchType": passenger_type,
        "passengers[]": dateOfBirth
    }
    req.prepare_url("https://www.thetrainline.com/book/results", params)

    headers.update({"referer": req.url})
    s.headers = headers

    payload_availability = {
        "origin": origin,
        "destination": destination,
        "outwardDefinition": {
            "localDateTime": localDateTime,
            "searchMethod": "DEPARTAFTER"
        },
        "passengerBirthDates": [{
            "id": "PASSENGER-0",
            "dateOfBirth": dateOfBirth
        }],
        "maximumNumberOfJourneys": 4,
        "discountCards": []
    }
    r = s.post('https://www.thetrainline.com/api/coaches/availability', json=payload_availability)
    r.raise_for_status()

    payload_search = {
        "passengers": [{"dateOfBirth": "1991-02-03"}],
        "isEurope": False,
        "cards": [],
        "transitDefinitions": [{
            "direction": "outward",
            "origin": origin,
            "destination": destination,
            "journeyDate": {
                "type": "departAfter",
                "time": localDateTime}
        }],
        "type": passenger_type,
        "maximumJourneys": 4,
        "includeRealtime": True,
        "applyFareDiscounts": True
    }
    r = s.post('https://www.thetrainline.com/api/journey-search/', json=payload_search)
    r.raise_for_status()

    print(r.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

As Sers's reply, headers are missing.

When scrawling websites, you have to keep in mind anti-scrawling mechanism. The website will block your requests by taking into consideration your IP address, request headers, cookies, and various other factors.